# Ubuntu can't stop mysqld

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I try running `service mysql stop`, `killall -s SIGKILL mysqld`, `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`, and `stop mysql`, but still I see this output from `ps aux | grep mysql`:

```
root     32302  0.0  0.3  59040  2120 pts/8    S    06:03   0:00 sudo mysqld_safe
root     32305  0.0  0.1   4440   772 pts/8    S    06:03   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    32651  0.1  6.8 426740 41388 pts/8    Sl   06:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

Comment: if you want to stop it with `init.d` - you need to start it with `init.d`. Now just try to `kill 32302 32305 32651`. And after that always use `service mysql start` to start it.

Comment: Did you try `pkill mysqld`

Comment: Looks like you tried to kill process without sudo. Why don't you use upstart: sudo service mysql start/stop?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `pkill mysqld`

Linux man page: [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Comment: For me, it did "kill" mysqld, but then mysqld automatically started again.

Answer (score 31):

The only thing that worked for me is partially explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227097).

If everything else fails, try this:

```
root@myhost:/usr/bin# initctl --system stop mysql
```

After that you can start controlling mysql normally using

```
root@myhost:/usr/bin# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Or

```
root@myhost:/usr/bin# initctl --system start mysql
```

Comment: /usr/bin/initctl doesn't exist in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: this works for me on mint. none of the kill, pkill,  init.d/mysql stop worked.

Comment: This is the only working answer I have found. And only the `initctl` way is working for me.

Comment: @HungTran, it does not have to. On my installtion, it is `/sbin/initctl`.

Comment: this is the correct answer, since all other options (`kill pid` or `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` simply respawn the daemon.

Answer (score 7):

If all else fails, use

```
kill -9 "processid"
```

or

kill -s "processid"

Comment: This failed too.

Answer (score 7):

You might be in safe mode.
Hence all processes will be respawned right away.

But the following should work.
Mind to replace root with the username

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

To restart

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who keeps seeing this when you try to kill mysqld_safe:

> 2019-05-06T14:47:13.251226Z mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
>   2019-05-06T14:47:13.253591Z mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
>   2019-05-06T14:48:31.097077Z mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
>   2019-05-06T14:48:31.102834Z mysqld_safe mysqld restarted

Use `killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe`
I think if you just kill mysqld_safe, mysqld will be spawned and when it sees there is no mysqld_safe. It treats as an error and start mysqld_safe again...This is my guess.